# Ubuntu 18.04.3 Can't get wifi working (Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174) or Bluetooth for that matter

Tags: drivers, realtek

My Lenovo Yoga wifi worked somewhere around Ubuntu 16.04 and then stopped. I've been trying various fixes for two years to no avail.

The wired network connection does work. The settings say "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found". Below are some results of various commands. Please advise of any further details and I'll be happy to post.

**lspci:**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)

00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)

00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)

00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)

00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)

00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)

00:1e.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO UART Controller #0 (rev 21)

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)

00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940MX] (rev a2)

02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

**uname -a:**

```
Linux lucas 5.0.0-37-generic #40~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 14 12:06:39 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**sudo dmidecode:**

System Information Manufacturer: LENOVO

Product Name: 80V5

Version:Lenovo YOGA 710-15IKB

Serial Number: MP18TR6B

UUID: ABE2FFFE-C9AA-11E6-B753-FC4596562B99

Wake-up Type: Power Switch

SKU Number: LENOVO_MT_80V5_BU_idea_FM_Lenovo YOGA 710-15IKB

Family: IDEAPAD

**dmesg | grep ath:**

[    9.256039] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3

[    9.286847] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to wake target for write32 of 0x00000000 at 0x00034400: -110

[    9.317522] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to wake target for write32 of 0x00000000 at 0x00034404: -110

[    9.348163] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to wake target for read32 at 0x00034410: -110

[    9.378728] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to wake target for write32 of 0xffff0000 at 0x00034410: -110

[    9.409185] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to wake target for read32 at 0x0003444c: -110

[    9.439645] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to wake target for write32 of 0xffff0000 at 0x0003444c: -110

[    9.470103] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to wake target for write32 of 0x00000000 at 0x00034408: -110

[    9.500563] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to wake target for write32 of 0x00000000 at 0x0003440c: -110

[    9.531020] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to wake target for read32 at 0x00034450: -110

[    9.561490] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to wake target for write32 of 0xffff0000 at 0x00034450: -110

[   13.143856] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: pci irq legacy oper_irq_mode 1 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0

[   14.313831] ath10k_warn: 154 callbacks suppressed

[   14.313833] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to wake target for read32 at 0x0003a028: -110

[   14.343972] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to wake target for read32 at 0x0003a028: -110

[   14.374108] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to wake target for read32 at 0x0003a028: -110

[   14.404244] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to wake target for read32 at 0x0003a028: -110

[   14.434378] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to wake target for read32 at 0x0003a028: -110

[   14.464514] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to wake target for read32 at 0x0003a028: -110

[   14.494651] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to wake target for read32 at 0x0003a028: -110

[   14.524788] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to wake target for read32 at 0x0003a028: -110

[   14.554927] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to wake target for read32 at 0x0003a028: -110

[   14.585064] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to wake target for read32 at 0x0003a028: -110

[   16.453444] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to read device register, device is gone

[   16.453446] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to reset chip: -5

[   16.483975] ath10k_pci: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -5

**rfkill list all:**

0: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth

```
Soft blocked: no

Hard blocked: no
```

**PLEASE HELP!**

Comment: Are you *sure* that you had WiFi working with this laptop? I don't think the Realtek RTS5229 is a WiFi adapter. What is the exact model # of your laptop?

Comment: See https://github.com/Zibri/Realtek-rts5229-linux-driver

Comment: @heynnema - that's not a WiFi adapter, correct?

Comment: @ajgringo619 I think you're correct... it's at least a card reader adapter... unless it's some kind of combo adapter in the Lenovo. The only other possibility is the "Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)", but who knows what the heck that is.

Comment: same problem for me... I hope some one will sort this out

Comment: Firstly, thank you all for the comments! Much appreciated.

System Information
        Manufacturer: LENOVO
        Product Name: 80V5
        Version: Lenovo YOGA 710-15IKB
        Serial Number: MP18TR6B
        UUID: ABE2FFFE-C9AA-11E6-B753-FC4596562B99
        Wake-up Type: Power Switch
        SKU Number: LENOVO_MT_80V5_BU_idea_FM_Lenovo YOGA 710-15IKB
        Family: IDEAPAD

Comment: @ajgringo619 - Yes, wifi worked on this laptop at one point in time. I'm not so sure if the RTS5229 is the wifi adapter. At one point in time, I thought it was the ath10k but I can't find that research now. I've been poking at this for 1 1/2 years. Uuuugh!

Comment: Just saw your previous comment. Can you add it to your question? It's really hard to decipher in the comments.

Comment: According to the user's manual, your laptop has an Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260 (which I don't see here) and needs the iwlwifi drivers (https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi). Does any of this look familiar?

Comment: I found my prior research. Stupid me. I updated the Subject and added content to the description.

Comment: This might help: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2323812